# ¿Como pasar datos de una vista laravel a un componente vue?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Tengo una vista en laravel con un input y la directiva v-model de vue, quiero que al introducir informacion en el input, esta se pase a un componente vue.

```
<input type="text" name="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search what you looking for ?">

<!-- Mostrar resultados de busqueda -->
<boxsuggestions-component v_bind:search="search"></boxsuggestions-component>
```

El props search del componente vue se muestra como undefined

```
 export default {
  props: ["search"],
   data() {
    return {
     search: this.search,
     products: [],
     page: 0
   };
  },
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu vista blade declaras tu componente vue:

```
<tu-componente :props_a_pasar="{{json_encode(tu_variable_en_php)}}" />
```

Luego dentro de tu componente vue recibes el props:

```
export default {
 props: ["props_a_pasar"],
}
```

Ahora te mostrare un ejemplo real en donde quiero pasar el id del usuario autenticado al componente vue:

En mi blade:

```
<mi-componente :user_id="{{json_encode(Auth::user()->id)}}" />
```

En mi componente vue:

```
export default {
  props: ["user_id"],
}
```

Luego con `this.user_id` puedo utilizarlo dentro de vue

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la directiva [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Con esto puedes enlazarle una variable al atributo de un elemento.

```
<input type="text" name="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search what you looking for ?">

<!-- Mostrar resultados de busqueda -->
<boxsuggestions-component v-bind:search="search"></boxsuggestions-component>
```

Comment: La variable props del componente vue se muestra como undefined

Comment: Si por lo que estoy viendo lo que quieres crear es una caja de sugerencias de búsqueda que se despliegue de un input lo que deberías hacer es que el input mismo sea un componente de Vue, y que boxsuggestions sea un componente hijo del input. En ese enlace tienes más información.

https://dev-notes.eu/2018/05/passing-data-between-vue-components/